# jQuery get dynamic id of html element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to update text in html element on AJAX post.

Element is in td. Problem is I have many td so I named it  `id="someTab.@user.UserId"` so every td has binded UserId.

I have this id in variable `var someTabId = "someTab." + userId`

Then I want to update its text on some action.
`$("#" + someTabId).text("some text here")`

And its not updating. I used `console.log` to check if `someTabId` is equal to its element id and it is

HTML Element I want to update:

`<td id="someTab.@user.UserId">I want to update value here</td>`

Comment: Show us the generated HTML please.

Comment: Edited question. td is not changing, its still the same. When I gave it some id and wrote this specific id directly in $("#someSpecificId") everything was good

Comment: it seems you are mixing razor syntax with jquery.

Comment: You need to construct your `id` attribute the same way you created your `someTabId` variable: `"someTab." + userId`.

Comment: @NegiRox Is right. Im mixing razor with jQuery. I have read that it is not good way but I have no idea how can I access to specific td with jQuery if I create them dynamically.

Comment: If you’re using dots in your ID you need to escape it since it is a reserved character used for class selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use instead of

```
var someTabId = "someTab." + userId
```

to

```
var someTabId = "someTab_" + userId
```

it will work.

**because "." is a class selector in jQuery.**

Comment: @zarpat please vote up if it's working for u.

Answer (score 0):

Since I got no answer I found a workaround.

I just refresh whole table in background by writing `$("#someTab").load(location.pathname + " #someTab");` in AJAX.